# JSON Data Types in XML

Tags: xml, json

The [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) dictates data types of NULL, FALSE, TRUE.  Is there a standard representation of these that is to be used in an XML string?  If you have a link to an RFC that would be particularly helpful.

Comment: You want to know how to represent NULL and booleans in XML? Is that the question? What does it have to do with JSON? Or you want to know how to include XML in a JSON string? What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: I want to know if there is a standard representation of these data types in XML.  If there is a standard, I think I can figure the XML document out by reading the standard.  I want to see a published standard or RFC if one exists.  I tend to use the PHP tag reflexively.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with JSON or PHP, correct? You're asking a question about XML? Something like this?: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/

Comment: OK, let me try to paraphrase.  How do YOU represent the boolean false when YOU create an XML string.  Does YOUR representation of false survive transport into other representations of the XML string in PHP or JSON?

Comment: Did you read [XML schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean)? Perhaps, `true` and `false` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Stan, perhaps that should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Charles, If OP find this info useful, I can post the answer (it's so simple and short though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a variety of proposals for mapping JSON into XML out there.  Among them:

- [JSONiq](http://jsoniq.org/)
- [MarkLogic's MLJSON library](https://github.com/marklogic/mljson)
- [a Microsoft JSON/XML mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924435.aspx)
- [piriti](https://github.com/hpehl/piriti) a mapping for GWT
- [the XForms 2.0 JSON - XML mapping](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/Json)

Half an hour with a search engine will certainly net you several more.

That list by itself should answer your question:  Yes, there are ways to represent JSON's NULL, FALSE, and TRUE in XML, and no, there is no *standard* way for any plausible meaning of the word "standard."

Different applications have different requirements and different tolerance for awkwardness; one obvious tension is between round-trippability on the one hand and colloquial or natural output on the other. No one has yet squared that circle in a way that has generated consensus among the interested parties.

Comment: You forgot [IBM's JSONx](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdatap/v3r8m1/index.jsp?topic=/xs40/convertingbetweenjsonandjsonx05.htm).  \*shudder\*